# intermediate fields of E/Q

Tags: galois-theory

Let $E$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{10}-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have identified the galois group of this polynomial to be $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^*=${1,3,7,9}. Clearly, the fixed field of $Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}E$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ and the fixed field of {$id_E$} is $E$.

Can anyone help me solve for the fixed field of the middle subgroup, namely $\{1,9\}$ ?

Comment: Did you try at all?  lol

Comment: Why don't you write out the elements of the Galois group explicitly as automorphisms of $E$ and see what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega$ be a primitive 10th root of unity. Every automorphism of $E$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ is generated by sending $\omega$ to either $\omega$, $\omega^3$, $\omega^9$, or $\omega^7$. The group of automorphisms is the cyclic group of order 4. Only one of these automorphisms (the one that sends $\omega$ to its reciprocal, $\omega^9$) is going to be of order 2. So the intermediate field will be the fixed field of the group generated by this automorphism, and therefore of this automorphism. It will be an extension of degree 2, so if you can find an element that is not in $\mathbb{Q}$ and is fixed by this automorphism, it will generate this intermediate field. Usually this element is a sum of powers of $\omega$, and in this case, it's $\omega+\omega^9$, aka $\omega+\omega^{-1}$. This element is clearly fixed by the automorphism that switches $\omega$ and $\omega^{-1}$. To show that it's not in $\mathbb{Q}$, notice that it's not fixed by all the other automorphisms. The one that sends $\omega$ to $\omega^3$ sends this element to $\omega^3+\omega^{-3}$, which is not the same as $\omega+\omega^{-1}$ (you can see by a basic geometric argument that both are in $\mathbb{R}$, but one is positive and one is negative). Since $\omega+\omega^{-1}$ isn't fixed by all the automorphisms of $E$ that fix $\mathbb{Q}$, it's not in $\mathbb{Q}$. So your intermediate field is $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^{-1})$.